# In android how do I count the number of lines in a image using openCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

This is what I tried.I got the output as a grayscale image in img2 of an Imageview object.

The problem is as lines.cols() considers everything as a line.

I want the count to be exactly the number of larger lines as shown in the 1stpic (I mean the lines that seperates the parking lot,in which the car can ocupy) [My output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4IXb.png) Can anyone guide me how to get the exact count of parking lines.I have used openCV version 2.4.I have been working on this for the past 2 days

```
 public String getCount() {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.park);
    mat = new Mat();
    edges = new Mat();
    Mat mRgba = new Mat(612, 816, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat lines = new Mat();

    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat);
    Imgproc.Canny(mat, edges, 50, 90);

    int threshold = 50;
    int minLineSize = 20;
    int lineGap = 20;

    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180, threshold, minLineSize, lineGap);

    int count = lines.cols();
    int coun= lines.rows();
    System.out.println("count = " + count);
    System.out.println("coun = " + coun);
    String cou = String.valueOf(count);

    for (int x = 0; x < lines.cols(); x++) {
        double[] vec = lines.get(0, x);
        double x1 = vec[0],
                y1 = vec[1],
                x2 = vec[2],
                y2 = vec[3];

        Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
        Point end = new Point(x2, y2);
        Core.line(mRgba, start, end, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);

    }

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);
    bitmap = bmp;

    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), bitmap);
    img2.setImageDrawable(d);

    return cou;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify one of the many answers regarding counting by OpenCV where kind of detection varies for every distinct case. You should make your own model for parking lines. Check some of these approaches/detectors  [Haar cascade classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html), [latent SVM](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html) or [Bag of Words](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html).

You could also modify some of the answers that works for something else like this answer below for coins, only you should search for shape of parking lines instead of coins:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/36111/how-to-count-number-of-coins-in-android-opencv/